# Install Ubuntu 18.04 and 16.04 and removing preinstalled Windows

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

I have a laptop with 250gb SSD which has Win 10 preinstalled. I need to install both 18.04 & 16.04 LTS versions on the same laptop for a project development. What's the best way to do this? I have downloaded mini ISO files for both LTS versions to have minimal installation size.
It's okay if I need to remove Windows as I have only 256gb SSD and only ~170gb left but what do I do with the Windows Recovery partition? Can I delete it too? Can I install Windows later normally using typical bootable USB method?
Screenshot below for reference. And how to give "/home" partitions for both Ubuntu's? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: 16.04 is EOL and 18.04 is going to EOL in 7 months. I suggest you install VirtualBox on Windows and install the mentioned versions of Ubuntu as virtual machines (guests) with _thin provisioned_ disks.

Comment: I would merge the Windows C: partition and partitions 4 and 5, then split the resulting 237 Gb partition into two roughly equal partitions. You can do all that from a live USB system with `gparted`. I wouldn't bother putting either `/home` folder on a separate partition.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a *supported* release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: There are complications with sharing a /home partition between different Operating Systems, especially if they're from different years. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is off-topic here, as is Ubuntu 16.04 ESM (*which still receives upgrades*) so we can't discuss that; but the problems are related to the software packages that will use shared data; can the different versions deal with the datafiles; will you be using features one version doesn't know about (which can cause corrupted data!) etc... That sort of data is on a per-package basis & you only mention one on-topic OS.

Comment: @FedKad - yeah I'm aware of EOL but it is just that the Single Board Computers (SBC) which we procured from vendors Phytec/Toradex are recommending those versions specifically to have good build environment. Also they are absolutely not recommending VM. These SBCs are their custom designs which they have tested in those specified LTS distributions only.

Comment: @guiverc - Yes, regarding /home partition I got confused. Usually I give separate partition for /home but if have 2 Ubuntu's on single disk, I guess I need to avoid this.

Comment: @Jos - yeah, that's what I'm thinking but will I be able to install Windows later? (which I guess should be Activated automatically on connecting to Internet). I wish to make 2 partitions with their own /home (by mounting / directly on 2 partitions).

Comment: I suppose you can always install Windows later, although it may wipe out your whole disk. However, that issue is off-topic here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)